# How can I use Vue.js route with data props?

Tags: vue.js

I want to make router like `DispatchManage/OM123456ES1`, `DispatchManage/OM123456ES2` by using `dispatchnum` data.

What I want to do is when I click `dispatchnum.name` and then user can see detail page like `DispatchManage/OM123456ES1` address.

What should I do? And also when data add, address should be add

Below is my code

-DispatchManage.vue-

```
<td class="text-xs-center" style="color: #53b4f5">
                    <router-link :to ="{name: 'DispatchManage', params:{name:item.name}}">{{ props.item.name }}</router-link>
                  </td>
                  <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.date }}</td>
                  <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.status }}</td>
                  <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.carNum }}</td>
                  <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.model }}</td>
                  <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.applicant }}</td>
                  <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.driver }}</td>
                  <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.applydate }}</td>

dispatchnum: [
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'OM123456ES1',
          date: '19/01/02 12:00:00 - 19/01/03 12:00:00',

        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'OM123456ES2',

        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'OM123456ES3',
        }
```

In router directory index.js

```
{
  path: '/DispatchManage/:name',
  name: 'DispatchManage',
  component: DispatchManage,
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue Props values not passed in simple test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56804187/vue-props-values-not-passed-in-simple-test)

Comment: can you tell me more detail?

Comment: It should be `params:{name: props.item.name}`

Comment: when I edit that params the result address is http://localhost:8080/#/{name:%20'DispatchManager',%20params:{name:props.item.name}} it  doesn't work

Comment: Did you use `to=` instead of `:to=`?